# How can I access Android libraries from a Web Application (browser)?

Tags: javascript, android, web-applications, browser

My issue is simple, I want to access a library from my browser, being in this case SensorManager.

I've found that getting alpha, beta and gamma from deviceorientation event in the browser is not consequent with the device orientation itsef, meaning that it may understand different values/axys among different devices.

So how to build a pipeline from a native library (SensorManager) to my browser? Any information will be appreciated.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

One way I could think is by implementing a `WebView` in your Web Application. In that you can access any Android libraries very easily. Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

> Hope this helps!!!!!!!